# reboot handling in linux

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, reboot

I'm trying to flush some data on service stop.
Based on documentation SIGINT is sent before killing the services, but looks like linux reboot command works another way. Maybe it works in force mode because of runlevel, but it doesn't invoke SIGINT, it kills all applications without any notice.
Is there any way I can handle reboot or change this behavior?

Comment: Superuser or Unix/Linux?

Comment: it is embedded linux

Comment: No, I was asking other users which site it belongs on. I suppose it's okay here, too. It is about programming.

Comment: How about writing a script for runlevel 6?

Comment: Runlevel reports 'unknown'.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that reboot sends `SIGTERM` and not `SIGINT`.
Change your signal handler to handle `SIGTERM` and you'll be fine.

Comment: No, it doesn't handle neither SIGINT nor SIGTERM. Looks like SIGKILL is sent instead, but it is not possible to handle SIGKILL.

Comment: @incognito Did you find out how to solve this problem?